# Download Files to web server from other site using php

Tags: php, curl, download, wget

is it possible to download file larger than 200 mb onto my web hosting directly so that i dont have to download that file to my computer and then upload using my ftp client.
and as i am not using ssh i cannot use wget. i was thinking of php or per or cgi may be..
(open to all ideas..)

```
+==============+                                  +--------+
|  Big server  | -----------+                +--->|web host|
+==============+            |   +------+     |    +--------+
                            +-->| MyPC |-----+        |
                                +------+              |     +========+
                                                      +---->| client |
                                                            +========+
```

or

```
+============+
| Big Server | ---+
+============+    |                      +----------+
                  +--------------------->| Web Host |
                                         +----------+
                                            |
   +------+                                 |      +========+
   | MyPC |                                 +----->| client |
   +------+                                        +========+
```

plz help....

Comment: What kind of access do you have to your web server? Just an admin panel, shell access?

Comment: what is available on your server, what permissinos do u have?

Comment: i dont have shell access just ftp;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For cURL

```
$url = "http://path.com/file.zip";
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: this finally worked as my host had closed outbound traffic on port 80. there was no error in the code...

Answer (score 5):

in php the easiest is probably:

```
<?php
copy('http://server.com/big.file','/local/path/big.file');
?>
```

however you should be able to execute wget. especially if external fopen is deactivated on your server which is very likely

using php just like:

```
<?php 
chdir('/where/i/want/to/download/the/file/');
system('wget http://server.com/big.file');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
system('wget -O /where/i/want/to/save http://server.com/big.file');
?>
```

curl is another way. you can execute the shell command or use curl php.

also make sure the folder (or file) you want to download to is writeable

Comment: looks like a server restriction then.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can download the file with this:

```
<?php
$in = fopen('http://example.com/', 'r');
$out = fopen('local-file', 'w');
while(!feof($in)) {
  $piece = fread($in, 2048);
  fwrite($out, $piece);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
?>
```

This requires two things:

- The local file must be writable by the web server
- allow_url_fopen must be activated on the web server

Comment: modified the page a bit (akx.x10.mx/akx/down.php) i am able to download files from my server, but other severs give the following error "failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /***" edit:oh just saw allow_url_fopen is disabled....... (:(